# Obfuscating JavaScript code

Tags: web-application, javascript, source-code, obfuscation

Some Flash developers are afraid of JavaScript. Their point of view:

Stealing JS source code is effortless, one would just 'view source' and copy it. Yes, you can decompile Flash bytecode, however it requires more time and knowledge. As a result, JavaScript is not suitable for commercial software development, because competitors will steal the code and put the original developer out of business.

**Does obfuscating JavaScript code make sense when developing commercial web applications?**

Are there any obfuscation techniques that actually work? Are large companies like Google obfuscating their web application code. For example are Gmail or Google Drive somehow protected?

Comment: FYI, SWF files can trivially be decompiled with [SWFScan](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Following-the-Wh1t3-Rabbit/SWFScan-FREE-Flash-decompiler/ba-p/5440167).

Comment: I've always wanted to try encrypting some JavaScript, then loading it with an Ajax loader that first loads a copy of the decryption key, then loads the (encrypted) JavaScript, decrypts it, and finally creates a `<script>` element containing the now-decrypted JavaScript.  I haven't tried because someone who's serious could crack that scheme easily and someone who's not serious isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: @BobBrown This is easy to break even if I am not determined. I can "Inspect element" and then copy/paste the code you decrypted for me. What you want to do is have code that the computer can understand, but a fellow programmer can only copy and expand and maintain with an effort exceeding the effort required for his own implementation.

Comment: @Alexander It can be trivially modified to slap it in a function and `setTimeout`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - And any knowledgeable hacker can trivially modify the downloaded startup logic to intercept the decrypted version. The hacker steps through what the browser has to do to run the page. Changes as needed (disable timeout). Worse, every button click that runs JS, needs unencrypted JS. You either leave it decrypted, or you decrypt on every button click. Those buttons are visible in DOM, as is their unencrypted JS that starts the decryption they need. Trivial to change.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve You could use WASM.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - ah, now that it is an interesting modern option. Especially once we can assume all browsers of interest support WASM - and refuse to run on browsers that don't [Internet Explorer; some mobile browsers in Asia]. Otherwise, hacker will load the page into an older browser without WASM.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think the operative word in the question here is "afraid."  The aversion is based on fear, not fact.  The reality is, the threat model isn't particularly realistic.  Commercial web software development companies nearly universally use JavaScript these days, obfuscated or otherwise, and I challenge you to find me even a single example of one that's had it's JS stolen by a competitor and then been driven out of business because of it.  I'm quite confident that it hasn't happened, and isn't likely too.

Too your second question, do companies like Google obfuscate their JavaScript?  Yes, but **not** for security!  They obfuscate to minimize the size of the code, in order to reduce the download size and minimize the page load times.  (See the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).)  This is not necessarily how you'd obfuscate for security because the only goal is to minimize the number of bytes that have to be delivered to the client.   This is what you should be focused on with JavaScript, not worrying about whether someone will be able to read it or not.

Comment: Additionally, the amount of time it would take to unminify (so, reconstruct the original logical flow of the program and translate one-letter variables into ones with meaningful names) would probably exceed the amount of time it would take to just write the functionality from scratch. And of course there's the fact that, since it's a web application, likely at least half of the logic is server-side, so the potential thief only has half an application (and if he doesn't, why use a client-server model?).

Comment: There's also the fact that there are plenty of applications which are entirely open-source, which don't get copied and resold verbatim for a variety of reasons. Atlassian JIRA is one such application; completely open-source, not often stolen. In large part because mainly people pay for support, something the original company will almost always do best. And also in large part because it would be both obvious and extremely illegal for someone to just copy the code. And obfuscating it further would just make it slower and more difficult to support.

Comment: can things like 'var _=_||{}' be considered as shrink the code?

Answer (score 9):

No. Obfuscating Javascript usually makes no sense whatsoever. Always assume that any logic you place on the client side can easily be obtained by a determined enough attack no matter how you obfuscate it.

Your "important" logic should be stored server side.

Comment: All obfuscators that I have tested produce code that can easily be reverse-engineered using eg. jsbeautifier.org or http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/malzilla/OldFiles/malzilla_0.9.3pre5.zip, but  http://www.javascript2img.com/ seems to add so much "carbage" code that makes it difficult to see where is the actual app logic. The downside is that they haven't released the code so we have only authors word that it doesnt add some tracking code etc. And it has a limit of 2000 lines, I have read somewhere.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to already know that obfuscation isn't actual protection, so I'm not gonna lecture you on [security by obscurity](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32064/at-what-point-does-something-count-as-security-through-obscurity).

What makes sense is this: Put your competitive code on the server to protect it, *then* obfuscate client-side code as much as you want. Granted, it won't give you much security but it'll definitely deter kiddies snooping around, and it'll create an impression of stronger security as a part of [security theatre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_theater). Google is doing it with GMail, Facebook is doing it.

Keeping in mind that your code **will** be deobfuscated, you can still obfuscate it as a part of your build process to make your clients and users happier.

There are many tools you can use to achieve that: [Free Javascript Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx), and [JScrambler](https://jscrambler.com/en/) (commercial) are two tools I've used before.

**Update:** After a discussion on [The DMZ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz), we've concluded that yes, Google and Facebook are doing it, but probably only for file size and performance and there's doesn't seem to be anything that suggests it's part of security theatre.

Answer (score 4):

Of course this is a baseless fear.

Javascript is only one part of a larger ecosystem, much more important is brand, site usability, site integrity, responsiveness and network effects.

Yeah, javascript minimisation, optimisation is good to do, but not because of these purposes.

If a competitor steals you code, you can go legal on their tails, and kill their reputation, but are they going to be so stupid (it is in the clear on their site too)?

And this argument can be made for html and images too, you obviously need to take down your whole website because people can steal it.

Personally I only obfuscate to hide my xxxxpy code ;) and take out the comments lol.

Comment: xxxpy?​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Pacerier xxxpy is a synonym for bad (code).

Comment: Why xpy?​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Pacerier in this case, I believe "x" is synonymous to "*".

Comment: @KnightOfNi, Then why ***py? What does py mean?

Comment: @Pacerier "****" would, in all probability, be "crap". "Crappy" is the adjectival form.

Answer (score 1):

It the code works, obfuscation is worthless. Take this example:
Before obfuscation:

```
function say(whatever){
alert(whatever);
}
```

after:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c]=k[c]
||c}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(ne
w RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('1 3(0){2(0)}',4,4,'whatever|function|alert|say'.sp
lit('|'),0,{}))
```

Now, not many people would really try to understand all of that mess, but if they want to steal it, they don't need to.

The obfuscated version can be called just like the original version: `say("hi")`.

If you don't know how the original version is called, locate the function/event where you get an alert and check if it uses a custom function instead of `alert`, Then use CTRL + F to find this function.

As a last resort one would simply parse the RegEx, in my example most of the "obfuscation" is just RegEx conversions of function names to the real ones at runtime. Noticed `'whatever|function|alert|say'`?

Comment: Well, no. In most cases, **working code** is useless if you can't look at it and use its underlying structure for your own pursuits. I think a copy/paste of your competitor's code on your website would be something of a giveaway, especially if he "hid" a variable like `author` somewhere in the obfuscated code. Still, that was a pretty cool example of obfuscation!