# Does "Security By Obfuscation" have any place in good security practices?

Tags: defense, obfuscation

One thing I've had hammered into me by pretty much every security expert I've talked to is that security by obfuscation is not a substitute for **actual** security measures. However, it has me wondering; are there any valid cases for security by obfuscation, when used in conjunction with other methods of security? Or does it not have any real effect on security at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The valid role of obscurity](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2430/the-valid-role-of-obscurity), [Is *all* obscurity subject to debate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178621/is-all-obscurity-subject-to-debate).

Comment: Obfuscation is not security. It can be very useful, but it is not secure.